# FFmpeg merge images to a video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

How can I create a mpg/mp4 file from let's say 10 images using ffmpeg.

Each image shall stay for 5 minutes, after the 5 minutes are over the next image shall appear and so on....

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your images are numbered in a sequence (img001, img002, img003..), use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/300 -i img%3d.jpg -r 5 video.mp4
```

(I've set an output framerate of 5 for player compatibility. Each image will still remain for 300 seconds)

If your filenames are irregular, and you are executing in a Unix shell like bash, you can run

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/300 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -r 5 video.mp4
```

---

For MPEG-2,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/300 -i img%3d.jpg -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 2000k -r 5 video.mpg
```

No idea what minimum output framerates are expected of MPEG-2. Experiment.

Comment: Thank, I will try this out, a question what do you mean with `*nix shell`

Comment: A question how would you do this if one needs an mpeg2 just name .mp4 to mpg ?

Comment: Ok I got one last question how do I change the resolution of the created video here

Comment: Add `-s 1280x720` for 720p..etc

Comment: Hi again I checked this again and the 5minutes thing does not work

Comment: this is my command 
`ffmpeg -framerate 1/300 -i pic%3d.jpg -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 2000k -r 5 wideo.m2v` but somehow the video is just 4:38 minutes long

Comment: You re outputting to a MPEG-2 elementary stream. If that's your constraint, use a standard rate like `-r 25`. First preference should be MP4. 2nd should be MPEG-2 program stream (`.mpg`)

Comment: Same as what you posted, change `-r 5` to `-r 25`

Comment: it is now 8minutes and 40seconds long

Comment: Output to .mpg with -r 25

Comment: BTW, elementary streams don't have PTS, so don't go by duration. Why not MP4?

Comment: Make a .mpg. Check duration and then run `ffmpeg -i video.mpg -c copy video.m2v`. The playback duration should be good even if it shows wrong.

Comment: hm the mpg is 50minutes long but the .m2v is only 40minutes long any guess?